# VBA If comparison TR\TD Elements

Tags: vba, excel, excel-web-query

I have a web query to a table that gives me a table like this :

```
     [C]                  [D]             [E]
[A] Events         |   IP source    | IP destination |
[B] MyEvent (1.10) |   192.168.0.1  | 192.168.0.3    |
```

the Html Code that gives  me  the info is on this type of schema :

```
<table class="wrapper">

<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="100%" valign="top"> 
    <center>
     <div id="contenpanel">

      <table id="contenttable" class="full_table_of_events">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="content" oncontextmenu="blablabla",( "src=192.168.0.1&dst=192.168.0.2")></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

     </div>
    </center>
   </td>
  <tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Soo i can get the value by the simple c0de .innerText the complete value from the innerText is :

```
myEvent (1.10) 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
```

I do grab this value cristal clear with msgbox , and i have this c0de in excel that what it does is , see were do you have the mouse on the worksheet and gives to a Label.form the Caption of what you got, i have 3 label.form's 1 for the Event, one for the Source Ip and one for the Destination ip and i try to see if that line that i have exists's on the table with a c0de but nothing happens.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Eventi.Caption = ActiveCell.Value
    Source.Caption = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1)
    Destination.Caption = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 2)
End Sub

Sub Extract()    
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim TRelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TRelement As HTMLTableRow
    Dim Chkb0x As IHTMLElementCollection

    URL = "https://localhost/events/index.cgi"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .navigate URL    
        .Visible = True

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Set HTMLdoc = .document
    End With

    Set TRelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("TR")    
    MsgBox Eventi.Caption & " " & Source.Caption & " " & Destination.Caption
    MsgBox "Search Starting..."

    For Each TRelement In TRelements

        If Trim(TRelement.innerText) = Eventi.Caption & " " & Source.Caption & " " & Destino.Caption Then                       
            MsgBox "Bingo! You have this event"                       
        End If                      
    Next
End Sub
```

Well I hope  someone can see what i'm doing wrong i just want to know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? Does the `If` statement not return **true**?

Answer (score 0):

A few debug points:

1. Step through your code and manually check each `Trim(TRelement.innerText)` value for validity.
2. Ensure the `Eventi.Caption` value is exactly "myEvent (x.xx)" including the space, parenthesis and case.
3. I'm not familiar with `HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("TR")`, but ensure it's not case sensitive.
4. As @Dick suggested, check for any non-spaces that should be a spce using `asc(mid(TRelement.innertext),8,1))`, where 8 is where you think a space is. If it comes back with something other than 32 (ascii for a space), you won't get a match in your `If` statement.

Comment: Also, do a `asc(mid(TRelement.innertext),8,1))` where 8 is where you think a space is. If it comes back with something other than 32 (ascii for a space), you won't get a match.